# Count values not equal to blank or zero in a matrix based off row and column data

Tags: excel, excel-formula

here is a simple table

| ITEM | EAST | CENTRAL | WEST |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 19.86 | 19.86 | 0.00 |
| 123 | - | 20.23 | 20.23 |

I have some items that have multiple prices in areas based on other factors.  id like to get a count of how many prices are set up for a given item in a given area.  I do not want to include blanks or 0s, so for the above id like a return value of "1" if I look for the item 123 for EAST or WEST.  I'd like a return of "2" if I look for item 123 for CENTRAL.  I think this can be done using variety of COUNTIF, INDEX, MATCH formulas but im not certain the layout of the formula.  could anyone assist?

Comment: Please share the expected result in the same format as your data or as a screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Count Matching Numbers Not Equal to Zero

**Legacy Excel (Copy Across)**

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$11=$F2)*IF(ISNUMBER(INDEX($B$2:$D$11,,MATCH(G$1,$B$1:$D$1,0))),IF(INDEX($B$2:$D$11,,MATCH(G$1,$B$1:$D$1,0))<>0,1)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no expected output shown hence assuming you have a data where you need the counts, then you can try one or other following formulas based on your excel version:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>G2</kbd>

```
=SUMPRODUCT((G$1=$B$1:$D$1)*(($B$2:$D$3<>"")*($B$2:$D$3<>0))*($F2=$A$2:$A$3))
```

---

The above formula needs to fill down and fill right, also change the ranges as per your suit.

---

Or, If you are using MS365 then can use <kbd>MAKEARRAY()</kbd> to spill:

• Formula used in cell <kbd>G3</kbd>

```
=MAKEARRAY(ROWS(F3),COLUMNS(G1:I1),LAMBDA(x,y,
  SUM((INDEX(F3,x)=$A$2:$A$3)*(INDEX($G$1:$I$1,y)=$B$1:$D$1)*($B$2:$D$3<>"")*($B$2:$D$3<>0))))
```

---

Or, this way as well:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>G2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     a, XLOOKUP(G$1,$B$1:$D$1,$B$2:$D$3),
     SUM(($A$2:$A$3=$F2)*(a<>0)*(a<>"")))
```

---